# In Visual C# 2010 Express, how do I add dots to the forms and see how big labels are?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I'm trying to learn how to make databases, using C# as the "master language".  I've installed Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express, created an application, etc.  There's a bit of a problem though.  The form on the GUI developer doesn't look normal.  Usually on these things you'll see dots evenly-spaced all across the form.  Also when you drag, let's say, labels on to the thing, it's pretty easy to gather exactly how big they are in both dimensions in most other IDEs.  Lastly between the dots and the ease of visibility - and control - of the sizing of labels, you can usally line labels, textboxes, and other stuff up pretty easily.

In this IDE that's not quite the case.  They've taken away the "coordinate dots", they've made the positioning of everything much more precise, you can't clearly see how big a label is after you put it down, etc.  My question is this:  How, if possible, could I switch the thing to the more traditional style in those regards?

I know my wording on this may be hard to follow.  I don't know the exact terminology of some of this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 Professional, you can switch to grid mode instead of lines mode from the `Options` dialog box, by selecting `Windows Forms Designer` then setting the `LayoutMode` option to `SnapToGrid`.

Can you try that in Express?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing off the IDE far too quickly - all this functionality is available in pro but can't vouch for express; perhaps you should try adding a bunch of controls to a form and dragging them round holding keys like [ctrl]  - you will probably find most of what you need is right under your fingertips it just different to other IDEs

Answer (score 0):

Like Frederic suggests the options panel contains some settings for the designer. Also `ShowGrid` can help with visual cues.

*However* I recommend using a LayoutManager like the `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` and using the docking/anchoring techniques which eliminate boring pixel perfection problems you'll get by doing the alignments yourself. I am of course assuming you're doing a "normal" winforms Form here...

Have a look at this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689.aspx